# Mysql LEFT to match first 3 chars

Tags: mysql, function, substring

Im trying to get all matching records from the `invoice_id` field where the first 3 characters are `RBK`, case sensitivity not important. I've tried to use the `LEFT` function in the bottom 2 ways but its not working. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
SELECT *, IF( LEFT( invoice_id, 3) = 'RBK') FROM `invoices` ORDER BY id ASC

SELECT *, IF( LEFT( invoice_id, 3) = 'RBK', 3, 0) FROM `invoices` ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `if` inside the select is not to filter results,if you want to filter result use `where` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE LEFT(invoice_id, 3) = "RBK" ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Worked, thank you! I'll accept answer once time allots it.